# Count the number of executions of a program using a file

Tags: c++, count, execution

I am trying to find the number of times the code has been executed using the code below. But it doesn't work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
    fstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open("count.txt");

    int count;
    outputFile>>count;
    count = count + 1;
    cout<<count;
    outputFile <<count << endl;
    outputFile.close();
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: What does the program prints to screen after two runs ? First run writes 1, second run should print two. what does it print ?

Comment: what does not work, what exactly happens?

Comment: When you debugged it and `count.txt` had not yet been created, what did `count.txt` contain at the end of the first run?

Comment: The program inputs the count correctly from the file, increments it (cout works), but unable to write to the file back..

Comment: It reads correctly from the file *when the file does not yet exist*?

Comment: there was a file count.txt with a number in it.. Sorry for the confusion..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend separating the concerns of (1) reading the file, (2) manipulating the data and (3) updating the file.

You should also introduce some error-handling and initialise your variables.

Here is some code to get you started:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    const char filename[] = "count.txt";
    int count = 0;

    {
        ifstream inputFile(filename);

        if (!(inputFile >> count))
        {
            cerr << "An error occurred while reading the persisted count" << endl;
        }
    }

    ++count;

    cout << count;

    {
        ofstream outputFile(filename);
        if (!(outputFile << count << endl))
        {
            cerr << "An error occurred while writing the persisted count" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

But this is not finished. Each of the concerns I mentioned above should be extracted into separate functions.

And then you have to consider thread-safety. This would be easy enough using locking.

But what happens when you execute multiple instances of your application **at the same time**? You'll need to do some file-based locking for this.

If you want to count executions on multiple machines, you have an even more interesting problem to solve.

Comment: Indeed, it's neither thread safe, nor process-safe. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
    int count;

    ifstream inputFile("count.txt");
    inputFile >> count;
    inputFile.close();

    count ++ ;

    ofstream outputFile("count.txt");
    outputFile << count + 1 << endl;
    outputFile.close();

    cout << count;
    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is writing it to another file.. But i want it to be the same file, so that i can keep a count of number of executions..

Comment: Yes, it will write to the same file as what you want. Please try it, you'll see.

Comment: Why do you think this is writing to another file?